# Basic Android code flow

Tags: android, android-activity

Lets say you have one main activity called "main", and other sub-activities that do some work and then return some data. Each time main gets called it starts up the sub-activities one at a time.

Main:

```
onCreate...{

Intent i1 = new Intent("com.bla.bla.activity1");
startActivity(i1);

//Get bundles from activity1 and save some variables..

Intent i2 = new Intent("com.bla.bla.activity2");
startActivity(i2);

//Get bundles from activity2 and save some variables..

Intent i3 = new Intent("com.bla.bla.activity3");
startActivity(i2);

//Get bundles from activity1 and save some variables..
}
```

If I understand correctly, activity1 will be created at first, and then destroyed. Will the code resume and start activity2 or will it just start activity1 again because the main activity was paused and then resumed (assuming we don't add an onResume/onPause etc..)?

Edit:

Lets say these sub-activities return one string each, and each string should be saved in one individual column of an SQL entry at the end of the main activity. The main activity should collect the three strings, save it as en entry and the destroy itself. 
For this to work, the main activity has to resume for example at intent "i2" after intent "i1" has done some work and returned the string. 
How is this result best achieved?

Comment: Whatever the answer to this question is... it's definitely not something you would ever want to do.

Comment: Why not? I want the main activity to obtain data from a bunch of different sub-activities and then update an SQL database.

Comment: I don't think you should branch off to other Activities in your `onCreate` or `onResume`. Consider starting the activities using `startActivityForResult` and handling the different cases in `onActivityResult`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Alex said, you wouldn't want to do that. You want to use the different Intents to call different Activities to create a flow to your program. Main might lead to Activity 1, Activity 1 leads to 2, 3, or 4. If you have several activities, you can use a switch statement to determine which activity you want to launch, based on conditions that are, or are not, met.

Hope this helps.

EDIT Answer:

If you want to save variables from different Activities, the you would want to start the second Activity from the first, the third, from the second, and so on. To create the data for the database, you can simply create an object, and then pass that object from Activity to Activity, using the `Parcelable` interface. Within each of your Activities you would want to use methods to save the returned data to the database, as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

That's what I've been doing all the time, but I think it would be more convenient for one activity to gather data from other activities. As I replied to Alex's answer, I want a bunch of different variables from different activities saved in one SQL database entry from the "main"-activity in this case.

Comment: I'll also add, that you can do that. You can create an object, and then use other activities to manipulate that object if you like, ultimately saving it to the SQL database. When designing your app, you want to keep performance in mind, and get in the habit of following a set of "best-practices", that way, when your apps get bigger and more complex, you will not have to adjust you methodology.